# Netbeans newbie-- How to enable viewing info from a javadoc JAR file

Tags: netbeans, jar, javadoc, netbeans-7

I have some JAR files which I have to add to a Java project- for each of those JARs I also have separate JARs that contain Javadoc for each of the jars-- now I want to be able to view information from the Javadocs in Netbeans.

How do I do this? I am using Netbeans IDE 7.3 on Windows 8 x-64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you download some JAR in zip, you will find usually 3 files in there :

```
example.jar
example-sources.jar
example-javadoc.jar
```

In your project import `example.jar` as libarary. After that go to your Project (right click ) then **Properties** >> **Libraries** >> **Compile** then select your jar file and click **EDIT**, in that form select javadoc and sources file :)

Here is image for easy navigation (itextpdf lib is in thi example)

[image: Netbeans project settings]

**EDIT**

There is even faster way ;) Right click on JAR in **Libraries** section of your **Project** and select **Edit** from menu. Its the same form as in example above.

Answer (score 1):

Go to: Tools>>Java Platforms>>Javadoc tab
There you can set what Javadoc you want to have.